# how to loop thru existing labels in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have hundred of labels in a web form, just like: Wall_1, Wall_2, Wall_3... 
I am using VB.Net. How to loop through all the labels names by just
adding the index number to the end of the "Wall_ " ?

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 20            

 "Wall_ " + i.ToString().Text = "142.5" 

Next
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

To loop through all the labels, I recommend using the method [FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx). 
Add them to your collection/list et voilá!

```
For i as Integer to 20
    labelArray.Add(Form.FindControl("Wall_" & i.ToString()))
Next
```

In order to change their texts...

```
For i as Integer to 20
    Form.FindControl("Wall_" & i.ToString()).Text = "142.5"
Next
```

EDIT:

As stated in the comments, the ".Text" attribute can't be applied to a generic control, so first it needs casting to a label:

```
For i as Integer to 20
    Dim label as Label = CType(Form.FindControl("Wall_" & i.ToString()), Label)
    label.Text = "142.5"
Next
```

Comment: Which namespace must be imported for Form.FindControl?

Comment: You've got it in the msdn link ;) get used to that webpage, it's really helpful

Comment: Ah, ok, didn't catch this :-) MSDN is always a good choice, that's right.

Comment: Just an addition to this answer.  I would also suggest not hard coding the number of controls to go through.  This is great when you know the number and it will absolutely never change, which is almost never the case.  I would suggest going through all the controls and if it's a label adding it to the array.  This will give you more flexibility in the future to add/remove labels, but also makes it easier if you ever need to grab other control types from the page.

Comment: Hi D le;  when i tried Form1.FindControl("Wall_" & i.ToString()).Text = "142.5" I've  got an error: "Text" is not a member of System.Web.UI.Control. It looks like it is not recognizing that Wall_%  is an existing label ?

Comment: My mistake, that error tells you that you should cast it to a label before setting its text... like
     `Dim lbl as Label = CType(Form.FindControl("Wall_" & i.ToString()), Label)`
     `lbl.Text = "142.5"`

By the way, take a look at MaCron's answer, great advice :)